# Does 'docker compose up' guarantee deletion before recreating a container that has changed?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Running `docker compose up` twice on a project will try to detect if any changes in the docker-compose files necessitate the recreation of existing containers. I want to use this feature, but it is extremely important, in my case, that docker compose must never run two copies of a given container at the same time.

In my experimentation and experience, it seems that docker compose always tears down a container before creating/running the new one. This is the behavior I expect and need, but I have not found any documentation explaining the semantics of this operation or offering any *guarantees* that this is, in fact, how docker compose will always and must always behave. Is there a specification or documentation somewhere that describes this behavior and/or offers assurances of this?

Comment: Not an authoritative answer, but a Compose-managed container will have a fixed name (either something determined from the Compose project and service name or overridden by `container_name:`) and you can't have two containers with the same name at the same time, which would imply Compose needs to delete the first before creating the second.

Comment: @DavidMaze Great point. I specifically configure `container_name` as well for that very reason with the *expectation* that even if this isn't somehow guaranteed it would at least fail in that case. I do find it hard to believe this is not the only possible behavior. But I would still feel better if there was some documentation on the semantics or at least someone somewhere has talked about it.

Comment: Inspecting [the code](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/61845dd7816cec9d42c715c8b157f88dfe78fd54/pkg/compose/convergence.go#L410) *seems* to indicate this behavior. However, there are enough goroutines going on that I'd need to really understand the threading model to be 100% sure no parallelism can get in the way. It's interesting to see that, after stopping the existing container, it does not remove it right away. It stops the old one, renames it, then creates the new one, and then finally removes the old one.